# What is the simplest way to change a Minecraft username for gameplay videos?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know how to make a video, that's not the question. The question is, how would I easiest make a series of videos where I watch player A from the perspective of player B, and player A has a different username in each video? I would prefer to do this with player A and B connecting over LAN and without buying lots of different accounts, but I suspect it may not be possible. Do I need a modded server or can it be done without one?

EDIT: I have accepted an answer because it works to do exactly what I wanted, but frustratingly it also has a side-effect which means I can't use it - the visible skin of a player with a changed displayName reverts to default. I'd much appreciate a solution which lets me easily control both skin and display name easily, preferably under LAN connection.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Are the usernames vital or do you just want players to look like different people?

Comment: I want the players to look like different people but this would include having different usernames as well as just changing the skin. I'm trying to achieve this in order to make gameplay videos that look like they have different players in without actually needed to buy multiple accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **LAN games** there's an easy way of doing this:

1. Locate your *.minecraft* folder (*%appdata%/.minecraft*)
2. Open the file *launcher_profiles.json*
3. Find the line `"displayName": "Bob",`
4. Change it to `"displayName": "Carl",` or whatever name you want to use
5. In the launcher it should now say *Carl* as well when starting the game

**Restrictions:**

- This does NOT work online. You'll get an error. You have to change back the name to the original one when you want to play online again.
- Inventory, Ender Chests, etc are tied to the name and a new name will clear them (until changed back).

Comment: This sounds perfect, thanks! I'll test it soon and if it works this will be the accepted answer as it sounds like just what I need.

Comment: I tested now and it works, thanks, hence accepted answer! However this unfortunately has a side-effect which means I can't use it :( If player A has changed their name in this way, then player B sees the customised displayName, but they don't see the customised skin player A should have - the skin is reverted to default! @dly do you know how to address this issue?

Comment: @Amorphia yes, there is a possibility. You can replace the Steve skin in your resource pack with the custom one and every default skin will then look like that one.

Answer (score 2):

CrushedPixel is your friend here:

He has made [a Spigot plugin for this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16ZCI_1Vf8U).

And [a way to get it in Vanilla with command blocks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ub3dfaVe5lA).

Also, if you use the [Replay Mod](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05rVWHtTevs), you don't even need a second account to record from an external perspective.

Comment: Thanks, this could be useful if I need to use a server, but it is more useful to me to keep it simple and use LAN.

Comment: Server or LAN is no big difference. I meant it as "in case you don't have a second account". Your worry was the number of accounts you need and with Replay Mod you only need one.